# String? != String in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm from the java android background. So can someone explain why a variable with type `String?` cannot be equal to a variable of type `String`.

```kotlin
var a: String? = "Kotlin"
var b: String = "Kotlin"

b = a // Gives error
```

What's the difference in both the types ?
Can anyone explain in java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In kotlin the "?" keyword indicates that a data type can take a null value. Variable "a" can take a null value, but variable "b" can not take a null value. You would need to make sure that "a" is not null before you could assign that value to "b".

Comment: Hmm.. so I can reverse them ? As the "a" can take the null value. I can assign "b" value to "a" ?

Comment: @AravindChowdary Yes, you could reverse them and assign the value of "b" to "a".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign the value of a to b you can do like this

```
var a: String? = "Kotlin"
var b: String = "Kotlin"
b= a?:"" -----> if a is null at some point of time in your code then b would be assigned an empty value
```

or

```
 b= a.toString() -----> if a is null at ssome point of time in your code then b would be assigned "null" string value
```

Answer (score 1):

The following prints "it's the same".
Are you using the correct comparison operator?

```
var a: String? = "Kotlin"
var b: String = "Kotlin"

if (a == b){
    println("it's the same");
}
else{
    println("it's not the same!")
}
```